# What is exactly passed as an argument if we pass Python function name?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop

Recently I was describing my code to my Uni teacher, it was something like this:

```
def f(x):
    return x*x

def map_list(function, list):
    return [function(element) for element in list]

map_list(f, [1,2,3])
```

and I told that in `map_list(f, [1,2,3])`, `f` argument is a pointer to the function, which is obviously wrong, as there are no pointers really in PYthon. I was trying to figure it out, but I couldn't find any clear answer. So, what is it? Reference, object, or something else?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's a reference to a function, as every name in Python is a reference to an object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Functions are first-class objects in python and as such you can pass them into functions and place them in lists, dictionaries etc. They are getting passed as object references.

Answer (score 0):

What you pass is a name which is bind to an object.
You can have several names bind to the same object, as in this example:

```
x = []
y = x # x and y are two names bind to the same object
```

If you call a function with a parameter you create another name (the name of the argument) bind to the passed object.

In your case the function `map_list` accepts everything that is callable with `()`. This means you can pass anything which has implemented the `__call__()` method. This is of course also the case for a function.